# Hazelcast write-behind with map.replace

Tags: hazelcast

It seems that the MapStore (write-behind mode) does not work properly when replacing some map items.
I expected that map items which have been replaced, are not processed anymore.

I am using Hazelcast 3.2.5

Did i miss something here?

Please see Server Test Class, Client Test Class and Output as well to demonstrate the problem.

Server Class:

```
public class HazelcastInstanceTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Config cfg = new Config();
      MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig();
      MapStoreConfig mapStoreConfig = new MapStoreConfig();
      mapStoreConfig.setEnabled(true);
      mapStoreConfig.setClassName("com.test.TestMapStore");
      mapStoreConfig.setWriteDelaySeconds(15);
      mapConfig.setMapStoreConfig(mapStoreConfig);
      mapConfig.setName("customers");
      cfg.addMapConfig(mapConfig);
      HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
  }

}
```

MapStore Impl Class

```
public class TestMapStore implements MapStore {

    @Override
    public Object load(Object arg0) {
        System.out.println("-->  LOAD");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Map loadAll(Collection arg0) {
        System.out.println("-->  LOAD ALL");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set loadAllKeys() {
        System.out.println("-->  LOAD ALL KEYS");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Object arg0) {
        System.out.println("-->  DELETE");
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll(Collection arg0) {
        System.out.println("-->  DELETE ALL");
    }

    @Override
    public void store(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
        System.out.println("-->  STORE " + arg1.toString());        
    }

    @Override
    public void storeAll(Map arg0) {
        System.out.println("-->  STORE ALL");
    }

}
```

Client Class

```
public class HazelcastClientTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        IMap mapCustomers = client.getMap("customers");
        System.out.println("Map Size:" + mapCustomers.size());

        mapCustomers.put(1, "Item A");

        mapCustomers.replace(1, "Item B");

        mapCustomers.replace(1, "Item C");

        System.out.println("Map Size:" + mapCustomers.size());
    }

}
```

Client Output (which is ok):
Map Size:0
Map Size:1

Server Output (which is not ok, as i suppose. I expected only item C)
-->  LOAD ALL KEYS
-->  LOAD
-->  STORE Item A
-->  STORE ALL
-->  STORE Item B
-->  STORE Item C

Any help is appreciate.
Many thanks

Comment: Can you create a ticket on github? Most of the developers are not frequently checking stackoverflow; but they are checking github. https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. I opened a ticket on github. https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/3386